# In python, Use RGB value of one image to create area of interest in another image

Tags: python, image, rgba

I want to program a visual search task in which participants are presented with a visual scene and have to identify a target object by clicking on it, at which point the trial ends. For each visual scene with embedded target (visual scene stimuli) I have an accompanying image that is completely blank except for the target (target stimuli), which is black, and in the same exact position as it is in the visual scene stimuli.

I have already created trials in which python pulls a visual scene from an image bank and presents it to participants, like so..

```
for i in range(numTrials):
    theTrial = trialOrder[i]                        # grab pre-shuffled trial index

    win.flip()
    core.wait(1.0)              # wait one second

    living_images[i].draw()
```

However, I do not know how to create an area of interest for the target for each visual scene stimuli and to make a trial end if that portion is clicked.

I imagine i should create a CSV with the visual scene stimuli in one column and the target in another column, then tell python to create an area of interest for each visual scene stimuli based on the RGB value of each corresponding target image(since they are blank except for black target in the same position as in the visual scene stimuli).

Comment: Some example images and corresponding stimuli would help. As would an indication of your OS and environment. Also your question is very littered with jargon - how does a *"visual scene"* differ from a *"scene"*? Surely something visual is just something you can see? How is an *"embedded target (visual scene stimulus)"* different from a target? If you want folks to help you, it is generally better if you make it easy for them ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Mark. I am using a Mac and and am using Psychopy (I think this is what you mean by 'environment', as I am fairly new to coding). And yes, visual scene= scene and embedded target=target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you are setting up your UI and how the user is supposed to interact with the images, but if your scene image and the accompanying target image is the same size you can use the accompanying image as a mask.

Have the user click on the image (visual scene) and catch the position they choose. Then check the value of the accompanying target image at that position. If the value is 1 (or 0 depending on your choice of "active" value) you get a hit and move on. Basically, you can use your target images as ROI.

edit:
Here is a small example of how it could be done

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(mask)

mask = np.zeros((50,50))
mask[5:10,5:10]=1

xi = 0
yi = 0

def onclick(event):
    global xi,yi,mask
    xi,yi = event.xdata,event.ydata
    if mask[int(xi),int(yi)]>=1:
        print('inside')
    else:
        print('outside')

cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```

The image shown doesn't have to be the mask image, but whatever scene you wish to show. For more on this check https://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html.

Comment: Thanks! 
I have many many visual scenes, each with an accompanying 'mask'. How can I link each mask to its corresponding visual scene, and further, define the coordinates of said mask by having psychopy read its RGB value? Also- Let me add here that I am using Psychopy.

Comment: @AliMomen You could save the images and masks in a nested list [[image1,mask1],[image2,mask2],...[imageN,maskN]] and calling n_list[n][0] to get the image and n_list[n][1] to get the mask of said image (where n is just the number of the image/mask pair you are interested in showing). I have not used Psychopy, but usually the mask image is a binary image where the "active" area has values of 1 and the rest has values of 0. The value you read from the user input is the image indexes (pixel coordinates).

Comment: I am very close to being done. The only issue I am having right now is that  Psychopy uses a different coordinate system for my visual scene, which I think is causing problems when trying to lookup mouse clicks in the mask image file. Because of that, psychopy doesn't realize when the target has been clicked.

Comment: And by different coordinate system I mean (0,0) in the middle of the screen for the visual scene

Comment: @AliMomen if it is in the middle you add half the width and height of the scene to the coordinates, or subtract depending on which way you are converting.